# Expression 'ILIKE' does not work in Filter

Tags: qgis, expression, filter

[image: Screenshot with ILIKE][image: Screenshot with LIKE-expression] The expression `ILIKE` does not work, if I try to use it in a filter.
Example:
The Filter

```
<"d_name" LIKE '%otter'>
```

finds the object `'Fischotter'` in the field `"d_name"`, that is correct.
But with the Filter

```
<"d_name" ILIKE '%otter'>
```

I get the warning `Ein Fehler trat beim Ausführen einer Abfrage auf, bitte die Ausdruckssyntax überprüfen.` (or `An error occurred while executing a query, please check the expression syntax`) And no result
What is wrong? I work with QGIS 3.16.15

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context (screenshot, sharing sample data) about the context? For me, it works, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8Fun.png

Comment: I just added to screenshots, the first with the warning because of "ILIKE", the second Filter with "LIKE" is successful.

Comment: What file format is the layer?

Comment: It is a gpkg-format (a point layer)

Comment: I just tried 2 other layers in the ESRI-shape-format (a point layer and a polygon layer): there I could not reproduce the mistake (ILIKE is working, though there is no difference to the behaviour of 'LIKE'). But with gpkg ILIKE is not working.

Comment: If I am right the ilike operator should be used with %otter% in your case, or perhaps %otte%. You could test it with ogrinfo/ogr2ogr command calls using the SQL options, it may be useful. Viel Erfolg!

Comment: if I try '%otter%' or '%otte%' it does not change anything around the problem with ILIKE (dpkg-file). What ogr2ogr is and how it works I don't have any experience.

Answer (score 5):

Please check [this issue](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/35698) in github. `ILIKE` is not working on GeoPackage.

Comment: yes, that is the same bug. I just tried it on another computer with QGIS version 3.22.2 - the bug still exists there too (ILIKE in dpkg-files).